# PHP how to render function from layout in MVC pattern?

Tags: php, oop

I've a code with im working for.

```
  class View
{
    public $model;
    public $function;
    public $content;

    public function __construct( $model )
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->templateLoader( get_class( $this->model ));
    }

    public function templateLoader( $model )
    {
        $template       = "View/Layout/" . $model . ".tpl";

        if ( file_exists( $template ))
        {
            $this->getContent( $template );
            $this->searchForTags();
            $this->runFunction();
        }
    }

    public function getContent( $template )
    {
        $this->content = file_get_contents( $template );
    }

    public function searchForTags()
    {
        $start = strpos( $this->content, '<%')+strlen('<%');
        $end = strpos( $this->content, '%>');
        $part = $end - $start;

        if ( $part > 0)
            $this->function = substr($this->content, $start, $part);
    }

    public function runFunction()
    {
        if ( $this->function )
        {
            var_dump( $this->model->{$this->function} );
        }
    }
}
```

This class load my template regarding classname. In the template if i have function 
example:

```
<td class="right error"> <% getLoginValidatorMsg() %></td>
```

i want to run it and replace into the value before it shows in my template. Somehow i cant run above function. Error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: LoginForm::$ getLoginValidatorMsg() in /media/htdocs/ver1/loginmanager/init/View.php on line 54
```

If i try to run:

```
$this->model->getLoginValidatorMsg();
```

will return me the value what i looking for.

Comment: It appears to be looking for your your method containing a space between `$` and `getLoginValidatorMsg`. Try using `str_replace()` to get rid of that space before sending it to `runFunction()`

Comment: Also, try adding `()` on `$this->model->{$this->function}` so: `$this->model->{$this->function}();`

Comment: Or use `call_user_func()` / `call_user_func_array()` instead.

Comment: yep, you were right. its whitespace error and also i added curved brackets. thanks for helping.

Comment: I just added it as an answer so there is no confusion with the other answer given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the error you have a space between `$` and `getLoginValidatorMsg` so you need to remove that space using a correctly placed `trim()` or just `str_replace()` on the whole thing. Also, it is saying it's looking for a property so you need to add `()` on your `$this->model->{$this->function}` so it turns it to a method:

```
$this->model->{$this->function}();
```

Alternatively, you can use `call_user_func()` / `call_user_func_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try add spaces. I think it'll be fixed

```
$start = strpos( $this->content, '<% ')+strlen('<% ');
$end = strpos( $this->content, ' %>');
$function_name = substr($this->content, $start, $part);
$this->function = $function_name();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class View
{
    public $model;
    public $content;

    public function __construct( $model )
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->templateLoader( get_class( $this->model ));
    }

    public function templateLoader( $model )
    {
        $template       = "View/Layout/" . $model . ".tpl";

        if ( file_exists( $template ))
        {
            $this->getContent( $template );
            $this->searchForTags();
            $this->render();
        }
    }

    public function getContent( $template )
    {
        $this->content = file_get_contents( $template );
    }

    public function searchForTags()
    {
        $start = strpos( $this->content, '<%')+strlen('<%');
        $end = strpos( $this->content, '%>');
        $part = $end - $start;

        if ( $part > 0)
            $this->replaceTags( trim(substr( $this->content, $start, $part )));

    }

    public function replaceTags( $tags )
    {
        $this->content = str_replace( $tags, $this->model->{$tags}(), $this->content );
        $this->content = str_replace( '<%', '', $this->content );
        $this->content = str_replace( '%>', '', $this->content );
    }

    public function render()
    {
        print $this->content;
    }
}
```